# Not recognized wireless interfaces

Tags: wi-fi

I have tried to use `wireless-tools` on `Termux` (non-root environment) and when i run these commands it does not recognize wireless interfaces:

```
$ iwlist scan
lo      Interface doesn't support scanning.

tun0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

```
$ iwconfig eth1
eth1    No such device
...
eth0    No such device
```

I know that *some* files at `/proc/net/dev` and it would be good to copy or *push* to this directory by using `adb shell`

**ifconfig**

```
lo: flags=73<UP, LOOPBACK, RUNNING>
        inet localhost   netmask 255.0.0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000 (UNSPEC)

tun0: flags=81<UP, POINTPOINT, RUNNING> mtu 65536
          inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 destination 10.0.0.2
          unspec unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500 (UNSPEC)
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo       no wireless extensions

tun0     no wireless extensions
```

How could i fix this?, is there could be another linux-based program to get a similar aproach?

**EDIT**
some files are missing in different folders corresponding to network system (/proc/net/.. etc)

Comment: Please do not use comments for additions to your question. Edit the question instead. `/proc` is a pseudo file-system so you can not anything in there.

Comment: 1. `lo` and `tun0` both are virtual interfaces; the loopback and VPN. Wi-Fi interfaces are usually named like `wlan0` or `wlp2s0` etc. (which don't appear in your list). // 2. `/proc/net/dev` is a virtual file created by the kernel to show the status of network devices. Copying anything to [`/proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) doesn't make sense. // 3. `/proc/net/dev` is not accessible to apps. So `iwlist scan` won't work without root, or at lest without disabling SELinux.

Comment: ok i am trying to avoid any third party service to set up wireless network interface

Comment: I just want to be able to connect in any way to my wifi router idk serving as external network or configure a connection between my device etc i am too lost in this kind of issue watched a lot of posts and reading many articles too confusing for me sorry and many thanks to clearly help me (: .